# No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-alpha09-6051327 available for offline mode. android 4.0 canary 9

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

### Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Cannot isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@2e602d09 of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform

  > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@2e602d09 of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
  >   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-alpha09-6051327.
  >       Required by:
  >           project :app
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-alpha09-6051327 available for offline mode.
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-alpha09-6051327 available for offline mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is as a result of Gradle trying to use some network resources but since you have `offline mode` enabled, it uses only the artifacts that it has cached locally. In AS Canary 9, **with your computer connected to the internet**, try disabling the Gradle `offline mode` using the button shown below, after which you can clean and rebuild the project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you thank you very much. I have been tired for that for 2 hours

Comment: This is so annoying, i am trying to find this everywhere in IDE for like 1hr, thank you :)